# Mapping a word "foo" to a domain name "foobar.com"

Tags: linux, domain, kubernetes

I need to map a word `"foo"` to a domain name `"foobar.com"` 
So it should be able to run `ping foo` or curl it.

> alias foo='foobar.com'

giving below issue.

```
curl -k foo
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: foo
```

this is run on kubernetes and domain name IP address is dynamic.

Basically I want to map K8s service name to a internal domain name which IP dynamic.

Comment: From [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash): _Aliases_ allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a server alias here.

**Option A (dirty ugly)**

You need to edit the `/etc/hosts` file for this

e.g.

```
${IP} foo foo.com
```

then you will be able to

`curl foo -H 'Host: foo.com'`

The host header is necessary as the vhost alias is foo.com

**Option B (clean and nice)**

Create a server alias, depending on your web server it may be different config.

On my apache httpd config I use:

`/etc/httpd/sites-available` - contains the config for each vhost

`/etc/httpd/sites-enabled` - contains the symlinks to the sites-available config files, this way I can activate/deactivate vhosts without modifying or renaming the files at sites-available, I just need to unlink to bring down a vhost

and I have modified the conf

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
[...]
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`
[...]
```

so let's say I had

`/etc/httpd/sites-available/foo.com.conf` and a symlinked version at `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/foo.com.conf`

then do

`cp /etc/httpd/sites-available/foo.com.conf /etc/httpd/sites-available/foo.conf`

modify `foo.conf` to match this:

```
[...]    
ServerName foo
ServerAlias foo
[...]
```

and then 
`ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/foo.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/foo.conf`

finally restart apache:

`systemctl restart httpd`

**Note** all these actions may require root or sudo (power user)

Assuming your system has a DNS server, nothing else would be needed; otherwise the /etc/hosts file will need to be modified too, but when you curl you won't need to pass a host header as the vhost alias will be foo.

i.e. in this case `curl http://foo` will work fine, while on option A you need a host header too.

Comment: Thanks. but  this is run on kubernetes and domain name IP address is dynamic.

Basically I want to map K8s service name to a internal domain name which IP dynamic.

Comment: use a server alias then, should be the easiest. I would avoid using bash/cli aliases in this case, the result could be very unexpected, otherwise the hosts file is your best bet from my POV

Comment: and I think this is exactly what you need too: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/ :)

Answer (score 1):

For your simple use case, you can use a variable:

```
$ foo="foobar.com"
$ curl -k "${foo}"
```

Do all of your use cases center on terminal commands?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need (the possible footgun) that are "global" aliases to do a mid-line substitution. These are provided by ZSH.

```
$ exec zsh
% alias -g foo=foobar.com
% print foo
foobar.com
%
```

However note that *any* bare use of `foo` will get substituted so if `foo` could also be an argument that *must not* be substituted then bad things could happen (hence, footgun—a command could break, or the wrong args could cause something else to happen, or…)

```
% print 'foo'
foo
```

so that's extra work you'll need to do with your brain to always remember when `foo` needs to be quoted versus when it does not, depending on how common `foo` is.

Comment: I would recommend to keep concepts separated, a bash alias vs a vhost alias :)